# How do I make a line feed in a div tag?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-2, html, linefeed

I have a text that have som `\n` in it. 
But when showing the text in a div there are no line feeds.

How do I make a line feed in a div???

I have tried to `Replace("\n","&lt;br /&gt;")` and `Replace("\n","&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;")`.
But the <br /> is showed instead of a line feed.

ASP.NET:

```
<div class="text"> <%: newsItem.Text %></div>
```

CSS:

```
.text
{
  color: Black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;      
}
```

Comment: Please can you format your question correctly... [see here for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  It is difficult to tell whether you are actually using `<br/>` or `%lt;br/&gt;` in order to make the code appear correctly in SO.  If you want things like `<br\>` to appear within your text, use the '`' character... anything within a code block (i.e. 4 spaces at the start of the line) does not need the character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
<%= newsItem.Text %>
```

Instead of:

```
<%: newsItem.Text %>
```

The second method implicitly HTML encodes the string.

Comment: `<%: "..." %>` is a shortcut for `<%= Server.HtmlEncode("...") %>`

Comment: nice one - didn't know that. (My previous comment - now deleted - was before you updated your answer from "first method" to "second method")

Comment: @freefaller fwiw, here's a blog post of Scott Guthrie commenting on the topic: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx